# FFMPEG unable to find a suitable option format for 'reconnect' error

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.core import command
import youtube_dl

class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': 'reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

This code for my music bot returns the error,

> [NULL @ 0000018dc5d76e40] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'reconnect'
> reconnect: Invalid argument.

Why? I have tried making sure that I am using hyphens but that hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: Hyphen missing before `reconnect 1`

Comment: Didn't fix the issue :(